# Need to add 0 to specific location of all elements that have a specific character length

Tags: r, string, dataframe, gsub, stringr

Lots of answers for how to add leading 0s, however my situation is this:

I have a dataframe where the first column are patientIDs, and for any that have only 3 characters, I need to add a 0 to the 2nd character of the ID:

```
patientIDs <- c("E015", "E04", "E212") #what I have
patientIDsnew <- c("E015", "E004", "E212") #what I need
hr <- c(110, 105, 135)
df <- data.frame(patientIDs,patientIDsnew, hr)
```

I figure I need to set up an ifelse where it counts the str_length, and if <4, it adds the zero...but not sure how aside from the first part:

```
library(stringr)
df$patientIDsnew <- ifelse(str_length(df$patientIDs) < 4,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using `sub` for a base R option:

```
patientIDs <- c("E015", "E04", "E212")
patientIDsnew <- sub("^([A-Z])(\\d{2})$", "\\10\\2", patientIDs, perl=TRUE)
patientIDsnew

[1] "E015" "E004" "E212"
```

The idea here is to match and capture the leading letter as well as trailing two digits only, in separate capture group (3 digit IDs will not match).  Then, we can replace by adding a padding zero.

Comment: How do you get so good at regex or whatever? The resources I find are very minimalalistic

Comment: @Ciney Yes, most regex documentation is very basic.  I guess you need to practice it to get proficient at it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a less efficient version because I suck at regex. Split the IDs at 'E'. Then, if any of the numeric IDs have a length of less than 3, add a zero. Then put them back together.

```
patientIDs %>%
  str_split_fixed("", n = 2) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(V2 = if_else(str_length(V2) < 3, str_pad(V2, side = "left", width = 3, pad = "0"), V2)) %>%
  mutate(new = str_c(V1, V2))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can get the `patientIDs` which has less than 4 characters, break the string based on their position and paste them together.

```
patientIDsnew <- patientIDs
inds <- nchar(patientIDsnew) < 4
patientIDsnew[inds] <- paste0(substr(patientIDsnew[inds], 1, 1), 0, 
                              substr(patientIDsnew[inds], 2,4))
patientIDsnew
#[1] "E015" "E004" "E212"
```